# create elements and set attributes inside each other with jquery?

Tags: jquery

Answer found :D

I'm new with jQuery and I know there are some really nice quick tricks do doing stuff so.. I know how to answer this question in JavaScript in 30 lines of code.

Current code:

```
$('<li>, <a>', {
    id: '#tab-' + count
}).html($(this).text()).appendTo('#uls');
```

I want to add a `a tag` with a dynamic `href`. Does that need to be done in a separate chunk of code or can I somehow integrate it with the current code.

What I'm trying to create:

`<li><a href="#tabs-1"> text describing url </a></li>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either have a mix out of jQuery element creation + HTML strings or pure element creation:

Mix:

```
$('<li>', {
    html: '<a href="' + some_variable + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a>',
    id: '#tab-' + count
}).appendTo('#uls');
```

Methodical:

```
$('<li>', {
    id: '#tab-' + count
}).append($('<a>', {
    href: some_variable,
    text: $(this).text()
})).appendTo('#uls');
```

Comment: actually the id was meant to go on the a tag so the Methodical solution is what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Phil: for more complex scenarios, checkout the varios javascript template engines.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything wrong with

```
$('#uls').append(
    $('<li>').append(
        $('<a>', { href: url, text: 'text', id: 'theid'})
    )
);
```

(I haven't tested it, though...)

Comment: +1 nice, but i think, it will add the a to uls, not the li. maybe you have to add a parent(). What´s about wrap?

Comment: Could you swap `.appendTo()` with `.wrap()`?

Comment: @Luke: There - I changed it a bit to be sure the appending works the way it's supposed to. Not quite as sexy (no chaining...), but it probably works.

Answer (score 1):

one dirty line

```
$("<li><a href='" + href + "' id='#tab-" + count + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>").appendTo("#ul");
```